# Rust "future cannot be sent between threads safely"

Tags: multithreading, rust, mutex

I'm invoking an async implemented method:

```rust
let mut safebrowsing: MutexGuard<Safebrowsing> = self.safebrowsing.lock().unwrap();
safebrowsing.is_safe(input: &message.content).await;
```

The **is_safe**-Method:

```rust
pub async fn is_safe(&mut self, input: &str) {
    let links = self.finder.links(input);

    for link in links {
        match reqwest::get("url").await {
            Ok(response) => {
                println!(
                    "{}",
                    response.text().await.expect("response has no content")
                );
            }
            Err(_) => {
                println!("Unable to get safebrowsing-response")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But unfortunately by invoking the **is_safe**-Method asynchronously, the compiler tells me that threads cannot be sent safely. The error is about:

```
future cannot be sent between threads safely
within `impl std::future::Future`, the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, Safebrowsing>`
required for the cast to the object type `dyn std::future::Future<Output = ()> + std::marker::Send`

handler.rs(31, 9): future is not `Send` as this value is used across an await
           ^-- safebrowsing.is_safe(input: &message.content).await;
---

future cannot be sent between threads safely
the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `(dyn for<'r> Fn(&'r [u8]) -> Option<usize> + 'static)`
required for the cast to the object type `dyn std::future::Future<Output = ()> + std::marker::Send`

safebrowsing.rs(22, 19): future is not `Send` as this value is used across an await
               ^-- match reqwest::get("url").await
```

I already tried to implement the **Send**-Trait to my Safebrowsing-Struct, but that does also not work.
Is there something I need to do to get it working? Because I have no clue why that is appearing

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The key of this error is that [`MutexGuard<T>` is not `Send`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.MutexGuard.html#impl-Send). This means that you are trying to do an `await` while the mutex is locked, and that is usually a bad idea, if you think about it: `await` may wait, in principle, indefinitely, but by waiting so long with the mutex held, any other thread that tries to lock the mutex will block, also indefinitely (unless you set a timeout, of course).

So, as a rule of thumb, you should never sleep with a mutex locked. For example your code could be rewritten as (totally untested):

```
pub async fn is_safe(this: &Mutex<Safebrowsing>, input: &str) {
    //lock, find, unlock
    let links = this.lock().unwrap().finder.links(input);
    //now we can await safely
    for link in links {
        match reqwest::get("url").await {
            Ok(response) => {
                println!(
                    "{}",
                    response.text().await.expect("response has no content")
                );
            }
            Err(_) => {
                println!("Unable to get safebrowsing-response")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to lock the `Mutex` later in the function, beware of the races! It may have been modified by other thread, maybe that `input` is no longer a thing.

Answer (score 18):

Use Mutex implementation from the async runtime you're using.

**Before**

Using [mutex from *standard library*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html):

```
use std::sync::Mutex;  // stdlib

let m = Mutex::new(...);

let v = m.lock().unwrap();
```

**After**

Using [mutex from *tokio*](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/struct.Mutex.html):

```
use tokio::sync::Mutex;  // tokio async runtime

let m = Mutex::new(...);  // the same!

let v = m.lock().await;
```

**But why?**

Roughly speaking, the native mutex forces the lock to be kept in the same thread,
but async runtime does not understand it.

If your lock does not cross with an `async`, then you can use mutex
from stdlib (it can be faster).

See the discussion from [*tokio* documentation](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/struct.Mutex.html).

Comment: This was the solution for me too.

Comment: Worked for me as well. The fun thing is that when I did not return anything from the function (only a `Result<(),MyError>`), it did not complain about it being a `std:.sync::Mutex`. Weird indeed.